# Leakage detection system along the pipe

Tags: design, sensors, pipelines

I want to design a leakage detection system along the pipeline that will use differences in pressure of flowing liquid (change in pressure between two points). Which sensor I should use?

Comment: That's going to be tough- How will you position the sensors so that you can pinpoint the leak?  The typical way to do this is to drain the pipe and inject helium gas into the pipe under a little pressure.  Then a helium gas detector is run along the length of the pipe (since helium is such a small molecule this works even on a buried pipe under asphalt) an in that way you can pinpoint the leak.

Comment: Unless you are trying to just detect the presence or absence of a leak- Then you might be able to use some sort of differential pressure technique, but if the leak is small it's still difficult.

Comment: if you want to detect the presence of a  pressure difference, just look for fluid flowing.

Comment: How do you expect this to work, given that the normal flow of fluid through the pipe will also result in a pressure difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leak_detection